# Чтение из массива объектов

Tags: php, json

Хочу из такого JSON

```
[
    {
        "y": "test1",
        "list_of": [
            {
                "v":1,
                "name": "value1"
            },
            {
                "v":2,
                "name": "value2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "y": "test2",
        "list_of": [
            {
                "v":3,
                "name": "value3"
            },
            {
                "v":4,
                "name": "value4"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

вытащить `name` и `v` и их значения:

```
$FirstJSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('list.json'), true);
foreach ($FirstJSON as $arrays) {
    foreach($arrays as $array) {
        foreach ($array as $jsons){
            foreach ($jsons as $key => $value){
                echo $key . " => " . $value . "\n";
            }
        }    
    }        
}
```

Вродебы все есть, но warning:

> ```
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in on line 20
> v => 1
> name => value1
> v => 2
> name => value2
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in on line 20
> v => 3
> name => value3
> v => 4
> name => value4
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас например `"y": "test2"` - не является массивом, вставьте хотя-б проверку.

```
$FirstJSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('list.json'), true);
foreach ($FirstJSON as $arrays) {
    foreach($arrays as $array) {
        if (is_array($array)) {    // Добавил
            foreach ($array as $jsons){
                foreach ($jsons as $key => $value){
                    echo $key . " => " . $value . "\n";
                }
            }
        }    // Добавил
    }
}
```

В следующий раз, постарайтесь указать на какой именно строчке возникла ошибка (в вашем случае: где находится 20ая строчка)